# ASCII Grid to Raster with DX/DY Cell Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have an ASCII grid file that has rectangular cells. The [ESRI](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/ascii-to-raster.htm) documentation does not specify how to convert from .asc to raster with a DX/DY value such that:

```
NCOLS 1900
NROWS 1100
XLLCORNER 115.834717
YLLCORNER 31.638744
XCELLSIZE ...
YCELLSIZE ...
NODATA_VALUE 0
```

I do not want to read into a NumPy array. So how would one do this, be it manually, in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest three steps workflow; (1) Edit header, (2) Import the file, and (3) Georeference it to its proper extent.

(1) Edit the header (XLLCORNER, YLLCORNER, CELLSIZE) to a dummy extent

```
NCOLS 1900
NROWS 1100
XLLCORNER 0.0
YLLCORNER 0.0
CELLSIZE 1
NODATA_VALUE 0
```

(2) Read this file by `Ascii to Raster`

(3) Georeference it by `Warp`

Source

```
0 0
1900 0
0 1100
1900 1100
```

Target

```
115.834717 31.638744
115.834717 + XCELLSIZE * 1900 31.638744
115.834717 31.638744 + YCELLSIZE * 1100
115.834717 + XCELLSIZE * 1900 31.638744 + YCELLSIZE * 1100
```

Above calculation comes from:

```
xLR= XLLCORNER + XCELLSIZE * NCOLS
yUL= YLLCORNER + YCELLSIZE * NROWS
```

Comment: Effectively thats what I had to do but I just got the extent from the raster layer. In our original grid file, we already had the LL and UR values, so I just mapped to that; this however will allow for quicker calculations in ArcPy. So there is no way to use XCELLSIZE or YCELLSIZE inherently?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as far as I know.